# Open a new website in lightbox doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, lightbox

I'm trying to create a lightbox with sub-website (google calendar) to not open it in new window. 
I used this lightbox site: http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/
Now when I open an image everything works but when Im trying to open my website it doesn't.

HTML:

```
<div id="poziom3" class="java poziomy">
<a href="http://www.natropiegra.pl/faq.html" data-lightbox="poziom3" title="Poziom3 

">Poziom 3
</a></div>
```

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because to open an external website you would need an iframe on your page. However the lightbox project you are using doesn't use an iframe. It uses CSS properties to open the image and give it the appearance of a lightbox. It is not using an iframe to load the image.

As the lightbox doesnt support iframes (is meant only for images) hence you are not able to open an external website (google calendar in your case).

You can try the following project. This has iframe support for lightboxes (see examples)
http://fancybox.net/

Comment: You're probably right but somehow I still can't manage with this. Thank you